How can I call the PokeAPI to get all the Pokémon at once?
I'm doing a practice assignment and was asked to use the Pokémon API to query and insert all of them at once. How can I achieve that? Should I use a Batch, a future method?
The service only sends one Pokémon per query.
public class PokeApi {
    public static string consultarAPI(Integer n) {
        String url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+String.valueOf(n);
        String responseBody;
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        request.setMethod('GET');

        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        system.debug('http '+response);
        
        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) { 
            responseBody = response.getBody();
            System.debug('Respuesta de la API: ' + responseBody);
            
        } else {
            System.debug('Error al realizar la solicitud: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
            responseBody='error';
        }
        
        return responseBody;
    }
    
    public static void deserializarAPI(Integer n){
        String responseBody=consultarAPI(n);
        
        String name;
        Map<String, Integer> statsMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        Map<Integer, String> typeMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
        List<Map<String, String>> abilitiesList = new List<Map<String, String>>();
        Integer pokedexNum;
        Integer weight;
        Integer height;
        
        Map<String, Object> parsedResponse = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
        
        List<Object> formsList = (List<Object>)parsedResponse.get('forms');
        for(Object form : formsList) {
            Map<String, Object> formMap = (Map<String, Object>)form;
            name = (String)formMap.get('name');
            System.debug('Nombre: ' + name);
        }
        
        List<Object> statsList = (List<Object>)parsedResponse.get('stats');
        for(Object stats : statsList) {
            Map<String, Object> statsMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)stats;
            Map<String, Object> innerStatMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)statsMap2.get('stat');
            statsMap.put((String)innerStatMap2.get('name'),(Integer)statsMap2.get('base_stat'));
        }

        System.debug(statsMap);
        
        List<Object> typesList = (List<Object>)parsedResponse.get('types');
        for(Object types : typesList) {
            Map<String, Object> typeMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)types;
            Map<String, Object> innerTypeMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)typeMap2.get('type');
            typeMap.put((Integer)typeMap2.get('slot'),(String)innerTypeMap2.get('name'));
        }
        System.debug(typeMap);
        
        List<Object> abilitiesList2 = (List<Object>)parsedResponse.get('abilities');
        for(Object abilities : abilitiesList2) {
            Map<String, Object> abilitiesMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)abilities;
            Map<String, Object> innerAbilitiesMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)abilitiesMap2.get('ability');
            Map<String, String> abilitiesMap3 = new Map<String, String>();
            abilitiesMap3.put('name', (String)innerAbilitiesMap2.get('name'));
            Boolean theBool = true;
            String hidden = (theBool) ? 'true' : 'false';
            abilitiesMap3.put('is_hidden', hidden);
            abilitiesMap3.put('slot', String.valueOf(abilitiesMap2.get('slot')));
            abilitiesList.add(abilitiesMap3);
        }

        System.debug(abilitiesList);
        
        pokedexNum = (Integer)parsedResponse.get('id');
        System.debug('Num Pokedex: ' + pokedexNum);
        weight = (Integer)parsedResponse.get('weight');
        System.debug('Peso: ' + weight);
        height = (Integer)parsedResponse.get('height');
        System.debug('Altura: ' + height);
    }    
}


Some additional details and clarification about your requirements would be helpful. Are you sure you need all 1000+ current pokemon and not just a subset? When you say insert, do you mean creating SObject instances and then using the insert DML statement? Assuming that you are creating and inserting SObject records, do you really need to do that in a single DML statement? I could imagine one or two ways to go about this (both batch and queueable ought to work), but relaxing some of the requirements would make things a bit more simple.

You can use either batchable or queueable, the designs will be nearly the same. You've missed one important part of the documentation. There's a list mode that you can use to get all available Pokemon, but you'll then need to call each endpoint to get more Pokemon data.
Start with https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=-1, which returns something like this:
{
  "count": 1302,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    { "name": "bulbasaur", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/" },
    // ... rest of Pokemon ... //
  ]
}

You can deserialize this with json2apex to generate the appropriate Apex classes. Next, you just have to iterate over the list, calling each endpoint, and putting the Pokemon into record format, then insert/update/upsert the records at the end. Keep in mind that you only have a limit of 100 callouts per transaction, so design your batchable or queueable to run in sets of 100 callouts.
In addition, use json2apex to also convert the response from a single Pokemon entry so that you don't have to deal with JSON.deserializedUntyped, which is useful for dynamic JSON, but kind of a pain to use if you already know the data types you're working with, which you do.
